# Зачем нужен wsgi между nginx и python?

Tags: python, django, nginx, wsgi

Читая статью про WSGI нашел такое объяснение

> WSGI-серверы появились потому, что веб-серверы в то время не умели взаимодействовать с приложениями, написанными на языке Python.

Тут все понятно, веб сервера выдавали какой то стандартный интерфейс запроса\ответа, своеобразные "протокол" в моем понимании, и python не умел его читать, соответственно появился wsgi который переводит сообщения между сервером и приложением на python.

Вопрос.
Это до сих пор так? Т.е. nginx до сих пор не умеет вызывать python напрямую?
Это характерно только для python или во всех языках нужна какая то прослойка между веб сервером, например в golang вроде бы не нужно?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под «вызывать питон напрямую»?  И wsgi это не прослойка, а протокол. Как http, например.

Comment: @AlexeyTen "напрямую" например пришел запрос на nginx, он сразу вызвал скрипт питона.

Comment: Нет, и никогда не умел. И тот же golang он тоже не запускает. Кто-то другой запускает сервер (на питоне, golang, js, чём  угодно) и nginx с ним общается по протоколу http/wsgi/fastcgi и т.п.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Если вы будет использовать модуль, который "вызывает" напрямую "язык" - то конечно никакие прослойки не нужны. Пример, [такой модуль](https://github.com/arut/nginx-python-module).

Или для PHP, [пример](https://github.com/rryqszq4/ngx-php).

Comment: Напрямую запускать можно, и собственно так изначально и было, скрипты хранили в `/cgi-bin`, веб-сервер их запускал, получал от них ответ, отдавал в браузер. Это плохо тем, что скрипт каждый раз требует время на запуск. Поэтому появились прокладки в виде протокола FastCGI и подобных. Скрипт уже запущен отдельным демоном и готов обслуживать запросы. Веб-сервер также запущен. Остается только передать запрос от клиента через FastCGI между ними. Суть проблемы - скорость. Тот кто писал книгу ввел в заблуждение или имел в виду что-то другое. В других языках также используется "прокладка" FastCGI

Comment: WSGI всего лишь описывает интерфейс Python-функции, принимающей и обрабатывающей http-запросы. Nginx не имеет к нему отношения, он ничего не знает про WSGI. Для взаимодействия с WSGI-функцией запускается какой-нибудь специальный питоновый веб-сервер (например uwsgi или gunicorn), который принимает запросы извне и затем запускает эту самую WSGI-функцию. А nginx просто копирует http-запрос в этот самый питоновый веб-сервер (через proxy_pass/uwsgi_pass/fastcgi_pass — в зависимости от того, какой конкретно протокол используется питоновым веб-сервером)

Comment: Но в принципе никто не заставляет использовать WSGI и запускать сторонний питоновый веб-сервер — можно написать свой http-сервер на питоне и использовать его напрямую. Например, некоторые современные фреймворки (вроде aiohttp или sanic) имеют встроенные в себя http-серверы и сами обрабатывают входящие http-запросы без использования uwsgi/gunicorn. Для nginx без разницы, какой сервер и на каком языке работает — лишь бы у него был совместимый протокол (http/uwsgi/fastcgi)

Comment: @andreymal "WSGI всего лишь описывает интерфейс Python-функции" вот теперь окончательно понял, спасибо! А что такое просто CGI, FastCGI в чем разница?

Comment: CGI описывает, с какими параметрами запускается процесс, что подаётся на ввод и какой ожидается вывод. FastCGI это протокол для сокетов, который тоже описывает, что на входе и что на выходе (по сути тот же самый CGI, только вместо запуска процесса все данные передаются в сокет какого-нибудь FastCGI-сервера)

Comment: Ну а WSGI это тоже по сути то же самое что и CGI, но вместо запуска процесса используется вызов Python-функции